# Who played iguana Spot in Genesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Memory Alpha is quite helpful when learning about all the background actors on *Star Trek*, even including all of the cats that played Spot on *The Next Generation*. However, I can't seem to find the animal actor that played the lizard version of Data's cat Spot in the episode "Genesis." Are there any production notes that state which animal actor was chosen to play the role of Spot? What kind of iguana was it (assuming it was an iguana)?

Comment: I don't believe this is known. It may be that the iguana was not named.

Comment: It was Janeway.   She went warp 10 just to be able to take the role.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - You just gotta know who to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the opportunity to speak recently to [Rob Bloch](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rob_Bloch) of [Critters of the Cinema](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Critters_of_the_Cinema) (who provided this [green iguana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_iguana), as well as various other animals seen in this and other seasons of TNG) and I am advised that its name was **Willie**.

You might also be interested to learn that this  multi-talented critter also played the part of the holographic iguana '[Leonard](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/PET+TRICKS+CAN+PAY+LAKE+HUGHES+MAN+TEACHES+ANIMAL+STUNTS.-a096189138)' in [VOY: Life Line](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Line_(episode))

[image]