# Who voiced Leonard the Iguana in Star Trek: Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "Life Line", a talking holographic iguana by the name of Leonard makes an appearance. According to [an earlier answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187497/who-played-iguana-spot-in-genesis), the iguana was physically played by a lizard named Willie. However, Memory Alpha does not list who voices the iguana in his single line,

> "Jerk."

Is there a source out there that says who provided the voice of Leonard?